# Dependent Dropdown internal server error(500)

Tags: php, yii

I found like this question in StackOverFlow.but I am getting different error.
I am try trying to implement Dependent DropDown in yii. the values are getting from the database to First Dropdown. but I can't get resultant output in Second DropDown.

Controller:

```
public function actionDynamic(){
        $data=Stu::model()->findAll('sna=:parent_id', 
              array(':parent_id'=>$_POST['sna']));
        // var_dump($data);
        // exit();

    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'branch','branch');
    // var_dump($data);
    // exit();
    foreach($data as $value=>$name){
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
                   array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'sna'); ?>
        <?php  
        $snaArray = CHtml::listData(Stu::model()->findAll(),'sna','sna');
               echo $form->DropDownList($model,'sna',$snaArray,
                        array(
                            'ajax' => array(
                            'type'=>'POST',
                            'url'=>CController::createUrl('stu/dynamic'),
                            'update'=>'#branch')));
                ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'sna'); 

    // var_dump($snaArray);
    //  exit();
    ?>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'branch'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('branch','', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select Branch')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'branch'); ?>
</div>
```

Table:

```
sid int
sna varchar(25)
branch varchar(5)
```

I followed this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/ to achieve dependent dropdown

it doesn't show any errors. but in network tab(f12 key) then change first dropdown it showing "http://localhost:8080/student/index.php?r=stu/dynamic" 500(Internal Server Error).

please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: What to the server error logs say? They will have a reason for the 500 error. Log location is specific to your server package. On LAMP stack, try /var/log/httpd/*errror_log or Google for your OS and web server package.

Answer (score 0):

> 500(Internal Server Error)

There can be a lot of reasons for this error to show up but since your application is running I guess there is something wrong with your code. Your code does seem fine except for these two couple of points that I guess might be an issue:

1. Change `echo $form->DropDownList` to `echo $form->dropDownList`
2. Change `'update'=>'#branch'` to the correct `id`, make sure `branch` is the `id` of the second dropdown, generally its `ModelName_name` so it should be like `'update'=>'#ModelName_branch'`. Inspect the second drop down in the browser to make sure what the `id` is.

Do these changes and see if it works now.

You should also enable error logging to check for errors, here is a [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging).

**EDIT:**

As answered by @Hearaman you should also change `$_POST['sna']` to `$_POST['ModelName']['sna']`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

> $_POST['sna']

In your ajax call Post data will go in the form of  `YourModel[property]`

```
EX:

Stu['sna']
Stu['some_other']
```

So, in your action dynamic `$_POST['sna']` cannot pick the posted value

Change:

```
  $data=Stu::model()->findAll('sna=:parent_id', array(':parent_id'=>$_POST['sna']));
```

To

```
  $data=Stu::model()->findAll('sna=:parent_id', array(':parent_id'=>$_POST['Stu']['sna']));
```

**OR**

```
public function actionDynamic()
{
    $postValues=$_POST['Stu'];        
    $data = Stu::model()->findAll('sna=:parent_id', array(':parent_id' =>$postValues['sna'] ));

    $data = CHtml::listData($data, 'sna', 'sna');        
    foreach ($data as $value => $name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $value), CHtml::encode($name), true);
    }
}
```